Reverse animation
Hello everyone if you can please help with the issue im facing below, the appbar currently transitions below top to bottom when a container is click, but I can't seem to reverse the animation once i click on close button.
class AppBar extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final BusinessPayload? selectedBusiness;

  const AppBar({super.key, required this.selectedBusiness});

  @override
  State<AppBar> createState() => _AppBarState();

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(
      selectedBusiness != null ? kToolbarHeight * 4 : kToolbarHeight);
}

class _AppBarState extends State<AppBar> {
  bool isShowing = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(alignment: Alignment.center, children: [
      AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0,
        title: const Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              'test',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                fontSize: 30,
                letterSpacing: 2,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              "test",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.blue,
                fontSize: 15,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            ZoomDrawer.of(context)!.toggle();
          },
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.menu,
            color: Colors.black,
            size: 30,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      AnimatedSwitcher(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        transitionBuilder: (Widget child, Animation<double> animation) {
          return SlideTransition(
            position: Tween<Offset>(
              begin: const Offset(0.0, -1.0),
              end: Offset.zero,
            ).animate(animation),
            child: child,
          );
        },
        child:
        Container(
          key: ValueKey(widget.selectedBusiness),
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Stack(children: [
                  Container(
                    child: widget.selectedBusiness != null
                        ? widget.selectedBusiness?.logo != null &&
                        widget.selectedBusiness?.logo.isNotEmpty == true
                        ? Image.network(
                      widget.selectedBusiness?.logo ?? '',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    )
                        : (widget.selectedBusiness?.coverPhoto != null &&
                        widget.selectedBusiness?.coverPhoto.isNotEmpty ==
                            true
                        ? Image.network(
                      widget.selectedBusiness?.coverPhoto ?? '',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    )
                        : Image.asset(
                      CoverPhoto,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ))
                        : const SizedBox(),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 10,
                    left: 10,
                    child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {

                        });
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                    ),
                  )
                ]),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ]);
  }

}

I tried to use a boolean and set an animation control to reverse but the image didnt show when the container was clicked

Can you add an MVP so I can develop an answer to your question?
